# Excel: Dropdown list dependant on other dropdown list

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu

I want the following in Excel:

Two dropdown lists in adjacent cells:

Dropdown list #1 | Dropdown list #1

```
Dropdown list 1:
One
Two
Three
```

If I select One in the first cell, the list in the second cell should contain these choices:

```
One:  
1.1  
1.2  
1.3
```

If I select Two in the first cell, the list in the second cell should contain these choices:

```
Two:  
2.1  
2.2
2.3
```

And so on. There are a lot of tutorials around, but I'm having some hassle figuring out which of them addresses this exact question.

Update: An example. When selecting f.ex. Group 1 under the Group heading (col A), the entries listed under Group 1 to the right (col D) should appear under the Item heading (col B). And the same for the other Groups.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update as promised:

When you're using a List for validation, you have to input a range as shown below.

[image: Excel2]

The [`OFFSET`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324991) function allows to to dynamically set a range based on its input criteria.

If you consider this:

```
=OFFSET(C1,0,0,1,1)
```

- Argument 1 = Anchor cell
- Argument 2 = Number of rows to move, you can use minus number here to move rows up and positive numbers to move down
- Argument 3 = Number of columns to move. Negative is left, positive to the right.
- Argument 4 = Height of the range (can't be negative and is optional, default is 1)
- Argument 5 = Width of the range  (can't be negative and is optional, default is 1)

In this instance, the range returned would be `C1` as we have no row or column offset and height and width is set to 1

The [`MATCH`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/match-function-HP010062414.aspx) function will return an index of where a value appears in a range of cells (range must be either 1 cell wide or 1 cell high)

[image: Cell Screenprint]

Based on the above screen print `=MATCH("Group2",D1:F1,0)` will return 2, as "Group2" appears in the second cell in the `D1:F1` range. ("Group1" would return 1, "Group3" would return 3, and "Group4" would return #N/A as it doesn't exist).

So based on that we can put the `MATCH` function in as our 2nd argument in the `OFFSET` function, and pick the column that matches the first argument in the `MATCH` function.

`=OFFSET(C1,0,MATCH("Group2",D1:F1,0),1,1)` will return back range `E1` as we've shifted the columns by 2 from `C1` because of the `MATCH`

`=OFFSET(C1,1,MATCH("Group2",D1:F1,0),3,1)` will now return back `E2:E4` as we've increased the height of the range to 3 and the row offset to 1.

And finally we can change the "Group2" value in the `MATCH` function to a cell value that will mean the range will dynamically change.

Here I've used Cell `A2` `=OFFSET(C1,1,MATCH(A2,D1:F1,0),3,1)` so whatever value is in cell `A2` will be used to offset the range.

And the last thing to do is to put the dynamic range into the validation (I used `B2`)

[image: Validation Example]

This will dynamically set the validation range.

[image: Validation Range]

When I'm using `OFFSET` function with multiple arguments and I'm not sure that it's returning back the right range, I wrote a small helper User Defined Function that I just put in a VBA module.

```
Public Function GetAddress(rng As Range) As String
GetAddress = rng.Address
End Function
```

This allows me to put the offset formula in and it will return back the range address. So I can make sure it's right.

[image: Get Address Example]

There may be a built in function for this, but I've never found it.

Comment: +1. For even more details Contextures has a bunch of pages like [this one](http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html).

Comment: I'm unable to use this line: " =OFFSET(HD2,MATCH(HA2,HD2:HD5,0)-1,0,1,4)" without getting the usual "Your formula contains an error" message. And that's after removing the H's, since my columns are named "A", "B" etc. and not "HA", "HB" etc.

Comment: @kakemonsteret if you update your original post with cell addresses your lists are in, i'll amend my screenprints to match..

Comment: I've updated the post with an exmaple. I don't mean to be difficult here, but I feel I'm missing something all the way when I try to follow the tutorials. The one at contextures, for example, looks fine but it doesn't work for me, and looking at it I really don't understand how it COULD work.

Comment: @kakemonsteret It's ok.. I'll try to add some more information about how it works..  Give me 30 minutes and I'll update my post.

Comment: Relax - I'm not in that much of a hurry :-) I appreciate your help. though :-)

Comment: @kakemonsteret I've updated my answer with some steps on how it works. Please let me know if anything isn't clear.

Comment: Great - I'll have a look at it :-)

Comment: Sorry, I just don't get it. All the lines you're posting, =MATCH and =OFFSET, give "Formula error" wherever I try to insert them. I might just be thick, of course.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41134/discussion-between-sam-and-kakemonsteret)

Answer (score 0):

*This solution avoids the use of the volatile `OFFSET` function.*

For the first Data `Validation` located at `A2` use this formula:

```
=$D$1:$F$1
```

For the second Data `Validation` located at `B2` use this formula:

```
= INDEX( $D$2:$F$4, 0, MATCH( $A$2, $D$1:$F$1, 0 ) )
```

The second formula uses the value selected from the data `Validation` in `A2` to `MATCH` the corresponding column in `D1:F1` and applies the column number to the `INDEX` function to return the whole column in range `D2:F4`.

[image]

*The function `INDEX( reference, row number, column number )` returns the entire `column` or `row` of the `reference`by entering 0 as the `row number` or `column number` respectively.*