# Excel List or Combo

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

Have 56 individuals that I want to list in a drop down box (Combo or List). I want to be able to select on and then select from a range of different options with the result being the correct info based on the option and the individual. How can I do this easily please

Comment: You want to create a 'dependant drop down list' or a 'conditional drop down list' in Excel. Take a look [here](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/dependent-drop-down-lists.html) or [here](http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel: Dropdown list dependant on other dropdown list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19955785/excel-dropdown-list-dependant-on-other-dropdown-list)

Comment: Have 56 people. Have a number of sheets in one workbook showing different stats. Want to use 1 sheet as a main menu so I can choose one individual from a drop down list and then select an option that will take me to the right sheet of information for individual

Comment: At the moment writing 56 macros for each of the seven options

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this (through to 56 though)?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67JbX.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEie9.png)

Data validation.
Google Spreadsheet:
1. Select the cell you want to create the drop down list,
2. Go up to 'Data',
3. Select 'Data Validation' from the menu,
4. Criteria: 'List from a range',
5. Select the range (you could leave an entire column for the items you want to list, should it ever be greater than 56),
6. Save

Excel (using 2011):
1. Select the cell you want to create the drop down list,
2. Go up to 'Data' sub-tab,
3. Click 'Validate',
4. Under the 'Settings' tab of the Data Validation window; Allow: 'List',
5. Source: (the range of values you want to appear in the list). Like in the Google Spreadsheet version, if you want to allocate that entire column to the data that should populate the drop down menu, choose, for example: =$B:$B

Hope this helps/is what you were looking for.
(Edit: formatting for clarity)