# Link a cell to a dropdown list in Excel

Tags: excel

I have an excel document that contains two worksheets, the first contains names, degrees and IDs for all students in subjects: Chemistry, Physics, Biology, the second contains a drop-down list to choose the student's ID and then only his grades appear. How do I create this list?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-drop-down-list-7693307a-59ef-400a-b769-c5402dce407b

Comment: https://trumpexcel.com/dependent-drop-down-list-in-excel/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel: Dropdown list dependant on other dropdown list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19955785/excel-dropdown-list-dependant-on-other-dropdown-list)